# Dissecting site to clone AJAX request and get XML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, android

I'm trying to develop an Android app that shows data from a site.

So here is the deal, i've got this site: http://gps.skgt-bg.com/Web/SelectByLine.aspx (It's in Bulgarian)
It uses ASP.NET and Ajax to get the approximate arrival time of the buses in my city, based on the GPS aboard the buses.

So basically you choose the type of transport (the first drop down list), the line's number (the second), the heading of the bus (radio buttons) and the stop, where you are at (third drop down list).  It returns the hour and minute at which the bus is expected to be at the stop, time of calculation of the result and a map of the bus stop. I'm only interested in the expected hour and minute.

I'd like to figure out the request that it sends to the server, so i can replicate it in my app, get an XML back and show the time in my app.

First of all i'm not that experienced in ASP.NET, so I don't know if there are some kind of security measures, protecting against this sort of thing, if so - i'm sorry of wasting your time, but my research so far doesn't indicate that.

Using Firebug i manage to figure out that it sends WebResource.axd some parameters identifying the assembly on the server that i'm interested in and a time stamp to verify if there've been any changes.

My question is is this doable, will the parameters change so much that my app will require constant updates?
And also how can i request the xml?

I see the following javascript code, requesting the xml in the site

```
xmlRequest.open("POST", theForm.action, true);
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlRequest.send(postData);
```

But I can't really figure it out, even though i googled the methods.
Does "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" mean that the url is encoded and I can't reproduce the request?

If you could point me to some literature to figure it out, i'd be very grateful.

Best regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I missed the part that you will be parsing from an Android app.  I put in an edit request to add Android as a tag.

Looking at that site, it should definitely be reproduceable.  Here is what I do in these scenarios.  There maybe an easier way to do this, but I know this works:

First, look at the request in Firebug and note all of the variables passed in, and whether or not the request is a GET or POST. Then use HttpWebRequest to hit this page passing in the same variables with the same method.  If you see that the output contains the data you need, you're all set, it's just a matter now of parsing text. Looking at that site, WebResource.axd is not the page you want to call.  It just contains Javascript.  The site uses a POST back to itself to regenerate the entire page, so look into that.

If that didn't work, you need to add some steps before you do the above.  Use HttpWebRequest to essentially recreate how a real user would access the site.  In this case, you'll be making your first request to http://gps.skgt-bg.com/Web/SelectByLine.aspx.  In conjunction with this, you will need to use a CookieContainer object to capture any cookies that get set so subsequent requests will send th pertinent cookie data.  This will help if the AJAX request was looking for cookie data.  Next, look at the AJAX parameters and see if any of them are automatic .NET parameters getting passed like __VIEWSTATE.  If so, you need to parse out your first call to find these values and use them when in the next request.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep at it then.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer your specific question about the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.  That type is a simple key-value format of the form `foo=&1bar=2&etc=morestuff`.  Keys and values are separated by equal signs and pairs are separated by ampersands.  It is the same format you often see in the query string of a URL.  This is by far the most common format for submitting data in a POST request.

That it is URL encoded just means that certain special characters are escaped.  If you have a value with an equal sign or an ampersand in it, it would screw up the format if that character were not escaped.  If you have a key "foo" with a value "apples & oranges", the ampersand would be replaced with `%26` and the spaces would by replaced with `%20` or `+`.  So the serialized `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data would be `foo=apples%20%26%20oranges`

You can play around with the encoding using a JavaScript console by using the `encodeURIComponent` function to encode a key or a value and the `decodeURIComponent` function to decode an encoded string.

There is some more information on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-www-form-urlencoded